# value?.min != nil ? value!.min : nil not force unwrapping writing Optional(some number)

Tags: ios, swift

```
func myFunc(array:[Int]) -> (min: Int, max: Int)?
{
    if array.isEmpty {return nil}
        var minNumber = array[0]
        var maxNumber = array[0]
        for number in array {
        if number < minNumber {
            minNumber = number
        }
        else if number > maxNumber{
            maxNumber = number
        }
    }
    return (minNumber, maxNumber)
}

let tempArray:[Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
let value = myFunc(array: tempArray)

print("The minima is: \(value?.min != nil ? value!.min : nil) the maxima is \(value?.max != nil ? value!.max : nil)")
```

In the given code I just wanted to make if for example, the code contains some value it will force unwrap but if it is not contained it will just print "nil". But in my code, if it contains number it will print Optional(some number).

Comment: `value?.min != nil ? value!.min : nil` is the same as just doing `value?.min`... So why?

Comment: It is not snippet it is full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value?.min != nil ? value!.min : nil
```

is a (conditional) *expression* and evaluates to some value which has a *type.*

The first expression `value!.min` has the type `Int`, but the second expression `nil` is an optional and has the type `Int?`. Therefore the type of the conditional expression becomes `Int?` and that is printed as "Optional(1)".

What you want is the *string* "nil", or the non-nil value as a string:

```
print("The minimum is: \(value?.min != nil ? "\(value!.min)" : "nil")")
```

(and similarly for the maximum). Now both expression in the conditional expression

```
value?.min != nil ? "\(value!.min)" : "nil")
```

are *strings,* and the result is a string as well. This can be abbreviated to

```
print("The minimum is: \(value.map {"\($0.min)"} ?? "nil")")
```

If you need this frequently then you can define an extension method on the optional type

```
extension Optional {
    var descriptionOrNil: String {
        switch self {
        case .some(let wrapped): return "\(wrapped)"
        case .none: return "nil"
    }
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
print("The minimum is: \((value?.min).descriptionOrNil)")
```

Answer (score 0):

So if i don't understand the question wrong. You can do:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Int {
    var valueOrEmpty: String {
        guard let unwrapped = self else {
            return "nil"
        }
        return "\(unwrapped)"
    }
}
```

`print("The minima is: \(value?.min.valueOrEmpty) the maxima is \(value?.max.valueOrEmpty)")`

Right?